# java - Want to divide long (huge file size in TBs) by some number (huge int) and safely get an int

Tags: java, int, type-conversion, long-integer, division

I want to divide long (huge file size in TBs) by some number (huge int) and safely get an int. But with the type conversion properties both int becomes long and the result is long. I'm sure my quotient will be an int, is casting ok or please direct me to a better solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well if casting is okay, then just cast!

```
long size = ...;
int divisor = ...;
int result = (int) (size / divisor);
```

Of course you should *only* do this if you're sure that the result will genuinely be in the range of an `int` - you could always check that of course:

```
long size = ...;
int divisor = ...;
long fullResult = size / divisor;
if (fullResult < Integer.MIN_VALUE || fullResult > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
    // Whatever, e.g. throw an exception
}
int result = (int) fullResult;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an explicit downcast:

```
long l_quot=l_size/(long)i_divisor;
int i_qout=(int)l_quot;
```

Comment: I think you meant to cast `l_quot` in the second statement.

Comment: Hope your variable naming and spacing are better in work. Underscores! O_o

Comment: @IgorRodriguez I do not work. I am a student, and am actually far out of my timezone to think clearly :D